# Comparing differences between discrete variables in two datasets of unequal size

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have two datasets, X, Y, containing discrete variables which both have a different number of instances. I want to analyse the difference between the datasets for each of these variables.

When these discrete variables are binary, I can use the Chi2 test (as suggested in [Chi square test when sample sizes are different?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/405170/chi-square-test-when-sample-sizes-are-different)) or Fishers Exact test (as in [Compare means of two datasets of binary data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86373/compare-means-of-two-datasets-of-binary-data)). However, one of these discrete features isn't binary and I'm struggling to find a test for discrete variables where the datasets are of unequal length.

This discrete variable is ordinal and has values 0, 1 or 2. Maybe one approach could be to treat this as a continuous variable and use a non-parametric test for continuous distributions like Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, but this gives me suspiciously low p values (e.g. $1\times 10 ^{-60}$). Another approach might be to bin the variable by setting 1 to 0 or 2, and then use one of the above tests, but this would skew the data and lose information.

Is there an appropriate test for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

While I was writing this question I found that the Mann-Whitney U rank test can be used here. According to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test#Assumptions_and_formal_statement_of_hypotheses), the test was originally developed under the asssumption of continuity but it can be used also on discrete ordinal data. Similarly the example given in [SciPy's implementation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.8.0/html-scipyorg/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.html#scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu) of this test is used on discrete ordinal data.